# View not appearing at bottom of CardView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Hi I have a simple `CardView` where I want to show a divider between each `Cardview`. The issue is, my `View` that I use as a divider never gets shown on the last `CardView` in my `RecyclerView`. Here is my attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/cv_news_feed">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp">

            ...Content...


        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/material_color_grey_300" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The divider shows up for every `CardView` except for the last for whatever reason and I'm not sure why this is occurring. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: Image posted:
[image]

Comment: do you mind sharing a screenshot?

Comment: @raxelsson posted a screenshot

Comment: The divider is actually rendered in the top of the `CardView` because it extends `FrameLayout` and you don't put any gravity to it. There are several answers now that will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CardView` is an extension of `FrameLayout` which means that your divider is not in the bottom of your `CardView` but in the top.

Place your divider in your `LinearLayout` instead.

Comment: Hey this actaully fixed it. Will mark this is the favorite answer thanks.

Comment: Cool, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Remove following view from your item

```
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/material_color_grey_300" />
```

and try to use ItemDecoration as follows

```
DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(
                Utility.ItemDecorationConst);
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(5);
```

**DividerItemDecoration.java**

```
public class DividerItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private int space;

    public DividerItemDecoration(int space) {
        this.space = space;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view,
                               RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        outRect.left = space;
        outRect.right = space;
        outRect.top = space;
        outRect.bottom = space;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your divider into `LinearLayout`,i.e.:

Answer (score 0):

Add `layout_gravity` attribute to the `View`:

```
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/material_color_grey_300" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to this code , hope this can help you

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/cv_news_feed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp">

                ...Content...

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cv_news_feed"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class **DividerItemDecoration**:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by Lincoln on 30/10/15.
 */
public class DividerItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private static final int[] ATTRS = new int[]{
            android.R.attr.listDivider
    };

    public static final int HORIZONTAL_LIST = LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL;

    public static final int VERTICAL_LIST = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL;

    private Drawable mDivider;

    private int mOrientation;

    public DividerItemDecoration(Context context, int orientation) {
        final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(ATTRS);
        mDivider = a.getDrawable(0);
        a.recycle();
        setOrientation(orientation);
    }

    public void setOrientation(int orientation) {
        if (orientation != HORIZONTAL_LIST && orientation != VERTICAL_LIST) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid orientation");
        }
        mOrientation = orientation;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        if (mOrientation == VERTICAL_LIST) {
            drawVertical(c, parent);
        } else {
            drawHorizontal(c, parent);
        }
    }

    public void drawVertical(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
        final int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
        final int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

        final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
            final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child
                    .getLayoutParams();
            final int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
            final int bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
            mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
            mDivider.draw(c);
        }
    }

    public void drawHorizontal(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
        final int top = parent.getPaddingTop();
        final int bottom = parent.getHeight() - parent.getPaddingBottom();

        final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
            final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child
                    .getLayoutParams();
            final int left = child.getRight() + params.rightMargin;
            final int right = left + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
            mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
            mDivider.draw(c);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        if (mOrientation == VERTICAL_LIST) {
            outRect.set(0, 0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight());
        } else {
            outRect.set(0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Then set the item decoration using **addItemDecoration()** method before setting the adapter.

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

// set the adapter
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

N.B. Remove the view that you are using in cardview layout to show the divider.

Answer (score -1):

You should use like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">

        ...Content...


    </RelativeLayout>

  <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/material_color_grey_300" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Because CardView extends FrameLayout so your devider will be behind LinearLayout content.